# Opening PDF file in ionic 2 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, cordova-plugins, jspdf

I am trying to make an ionic 2 app. I have a pdf generated using jsPDF.

The code for the same is

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontStyle('Bold');
doc.setFontSize(14);
doc.text('Testing PDFs', 20, 20);
```

Now I want to save the open the PDF in the mobile app,

but `doc.output('save', 'tester.pdf');` doesn't seem to work in the mobile app.

Please can you tell me which plugin can I install so as to view and share the newly made pdf.

Comment: best way is download and view in default pdf viewer. I am doing same working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to use [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to create a PDF. Then one has to use `blob` attribute to convert it to the format that can be used by the application to allow passing in the app before putting it on screen.

After the blob step, One has to install [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) on the command line by the command
`npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save` and use the `<pdf-viewer>` to view it on the mobile app screen.

Make sure you import the the ng-pdf-viewer in the *app.module.ts* file in the import statements and in the `@NgModule.`

Here is the code for the same,

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontStyle('Bold');
doc.setFontSize(14);
doc.text('Testing PDFs', 20, 20);
var blob = doc.output('blob', {type: 'application/pdf'});
let pdfUrl = {pdfUrl: URL.createObjectURL(blob)};
let modal = this.navCtrl.push(ResumeView, pdfUrl);
```

in the ResumeView

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-resume-view',
  templateUrl: '<ion-content padding text-center>
                   <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfUrl" 
                               [page]="page" 
                               [original-size]="false"
                               style="display: block;">

                    </pdf-viewer>
                </ion-content>',
})
export class ResumeView {
  pdfUrl : String;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ResumeView');
    this.pdfUrl = this.navParams.get('pdfUrl');
   }

}
```

Comment: instead of using templateUrl, I think you should use "template".

Comment: @Mayur , @Mankeomorakort 

I have installed jspdf through "npm install jspdf".

then I have included 
` "script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.debug.js" "/script" `
in index.html

after that when I declaring "var doc = new jspdf() "

it is giving me error that cannot found jspdf.

I am working on Ionic 2 project 
Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: i am not able to scroll with that

Answer (score 10):

I think includes script via external URL may not a good option in ionic. There is an other way as below:

**1-Install ng2-pdf-viewer module**

```
npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save
```

And import **PdfViewerComponent** in your app.moudle.ts as below:

[image]

**2- Instead of including jspdf.debug.‌​js via extenal url, you can  install jspdf module**

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

**3- Implement ionic copy custom script**

Create scripts folder in root of your ionic project and create a file name copy-custom-libs.js inside scripts folder.

```
module.exports = {
  copyCustomScript: {
    src: ["{{ROOT}}/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"],
    dest: "{{WWW}}/assets"
  }
}
```

In package.json, add config attribute at bottom as below:

```
 "config": {
      "ionic_copy": "./scripts/copy-custom-libs.js"
  }
```

[image]

Update index.html and add jspdf.min.js from your assets folder.

```
<script src="assets/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

**4-Finally, you can write code as below:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

The source code of this example can be found here: [ionic pdf viewer](https://github.com/ManKeomorakort/ionic3-benchmark)

I Hope this could help you, Thanks :)

Comment: Good guide in detail to follow

Comment: How that `ionic_copy` auto executed from json?

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple

step:1) install pdf-viewer plugin:

```
     npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save
```

step:2) in your app.module.ts:

```
   import { PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

   @NgModule({
           declarations: [
              PdfViewerComponent,
            ],
```

step:3)in app.component.ts:

```
      import { PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
```

step:4) in your page html file:

```
 <ion-content>
 <pdf-viewer [src]="'YOUR_PDF_FILE_PATH'" [page]="page" [original-size]="false" style="display:block;"> </pdf-viewer>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: When I try it, only worked on android not on ios. Is that same for you?

Comment: install this version npm install ng2-pdf-viewer@4.1.1 & try again

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener


this.fileOpener.open('path/to/file.pdf', 'application/pdf')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
```

Ref : [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/)

Comment: It trys to open pdf file with the app having package name de.sitewaerts.cleverdox.viewer we want to open inside app not on any other third party app.

Comment: yes you are right, check answer again. this working great

Comment: Can we provide path/to/file.pdf as url from server ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

In Component part:

```
    import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    url :any;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.amu.ac.in/pdf/FreeResources.pdf');
```

In HTML part :

```
<iframe  [src]="url" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Comment: its not woking in the iphone devices but only working  in android devices?