# How to import External JavaScript library pdfmake in Ionic (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use **External JavaScript library pdfmake in Ionic 2(typescript).**

Can any body please guide me how to import and use this library ?

library link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake

Comment: link is 404 not found

Comment: @ShehramTahir, please check my instruction here for importing javascript library [Import javascript in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730612/opening-pdf-file-in-ionic-2-app)

Comment: @Mankeomorakort are you sure? It looks like pdf viewer module.. Is it same as pdfmake?

Comment: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/864 maybe check this

Comment: If i import the libraries like this

`
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
`

it gives error that not found
@suraj

Comment: @mallaudin Yes it is difference, By my instruction could guide Shehram Tahir  to understand how to use any javascript library in Ionic.